# I can not modify the onchange field of an object cloned javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, onchange, getelementbyid

I have a problem when editing the html onchange attribute not let me do it. My code HTML is:

```
<table id="insertar">
                <tr><td>Producto</td><td>Stock</td><td>Cantidad</td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                <select id="p1" name="producto[]" onChange="document.getElementById('stock1').value = setStock('p1')" >
        <option value="" >---------</option>
                <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" id="stock1" value="" name="stock[]" readonly /></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='cantidad[]' required /></td></tr>
            </table>
      <a href="#" onclick="addRow()" >Agregar otro</a>
```

And my code Javascript is:

```
var _default;
var counter=2;
window.onload=function(){
    var x=document.getElementById("insertar").tBodies[0];
    _default =x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);  
}
function addRow(){
    var c=0;
    var x=document.getElementById("insertar").tBodies[0];
    Array.prototype.slice.call(_default.childNodes, 0).forEach(function(value){
        Array.prototype.slice.call(value.childNodes, 0).forEach(function(value1){
            if((value1.nodeType === 1) && (c === 0)){
                value1.id="p" + counter;
value1.onchange="document.getElementById(\"stock"+counter+"\").value = setStock(\"p"+counter+"\")";
                c++;
            }else if((value1.nodeType === 1) && (c === 1)){
                value1.id = "stock" + counter;
                c++;
            }
        });  
    });  
    counter++;
    x.appendChild(_default.cloneNode(true));
}
```

If I work all right, just that I can not change the value onchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my answer. I use:

```
function addRow(){
    var c=0;
    var x=document.getElementById("insertar").tBodies[0];
    Array.prototype.slice.call(_default.childNodes, 0).forEach(function(value){
        Array.prototype.slice.call(value.childNodes, 0).forEach(function(value1){
            if((value1.nodeType === 1) && (c === 0)){
                value1.id="p" + counter;
                value1.setAttribute("onchange","document.getElementById('stock"+counter+"').value = setStock(this.id)");
                c++;
            }else if((value1.nodeType === 1) && (c === 1)){
                value1.id = "stock" + counter;
                c++;
            }
        });  
    });  
    counter++;
    x.appendChild(_default.cloneNode(true));
}
```